# Accessing Cognito user attributes from Appsync

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

Imagine that you have a simple AWS stack with Appsync, Aurora RDS and Cognito.

Obviously, Cognito manages the users registration process, where each user has a few attributes, let's say `email`, `first_name`, and `last_name`.

Also there is a table called `users` in Aurora RDS, which, among other columns, has the `cognito_id` column where it stores the reference to the Cognito users' IDs.

The last thing is AppSync GraphQL query that would list all the available users with fields that should come both from the `users` RDS table and Cognito attributes. And that's where the question arises.

If it was needed to only fetch attributes from the `users` table, the problem would be solved with some small and tidy SQL query that could be put into the AppSync VTL request template. But since it's also required to get the attributes from the Cognito users pool, things get complicated.

How could something like that be done in an efficient and scalable way? Or is it a bad design and there's a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

My experience tells me not to have a table Users when we use Cognito. All data we can hold in Cognito attributes. But maybe it required for you. However, you can use Lambda function as AppSync data source. And get data from Cognito in Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me in the past is to delegate User management to Cognito. So Cognito will handle authentication and authorization. I set up a post-confirmation lambda, that creates a record in the users table in the database.
The users table has a column for cognito_sub that can be used to reference it.